# camera program gives error when run in /etc/profile but the program runs fine

Tags: python, boot, led, picamera, raspberry-pi-desktop

This is the error I get :
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to enable connection: Out of resources

```
import numpy as np
import os
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep
from gpiozero import LED

l = LED(21)

camera = PiCamera()
camera.rotation = 180
filename = "frame.png"

while 1:
    try:
        camera.capture(filename)
        f = Image.open(filename)
        is_light = np.mean(np.asarray(f)) > 120

        if is_light:
            print("off")
            l.off()

        else:
            print("on")
            l.on()

        os.remove(filename)

    except Exception as e:
        camera.close()
        print(e)
        break


    sleep(2)

quit()
```

Now if run the above code in Thonny or mu or even with putty it works without errors but does not work if in /etc/profile

What do I do to either solve the error  or atleast how to run the program on startup

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what error your are having, but check out this page for information about running programs on the rasrpberry pi on startup.

https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-run-a-raspberry-pi-program-on-startup#